# Selecting data from a database (Yii)

Tags: php, database, activerecord, loops, yii

I've been getting in to Yii, and I would like to know how to select data from a database and loop through the rows. I've done this in CodeIgniter and I can't find anywhere which documents how I would go about doing this. I have the code:

```
$models = TblMess::model()->findAll(array(
'condition' => 'messid > :minid',
'params' => array(':minid' => '1'),
));
```

which should select all rows where the message ID is larger than one. How do I loop through all the rows selected and do something with them? eg.

```
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo 'Message: '.$row['message'].'. Created at: '.$row['time'].'.';
}
```

This seems like a simple question, but I think I'm missing something!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($models as $model) {
    echo 'Message: ', $model->message, '. Created at: ', $model->time, '.';
}
```

should work. Data queried through CActiveRecord classes is returned as objects (in this case, instances of `TblMess` class), not as arrays.